# What would be image size for mobile websites to accommodate 100% of available screen?

Tags: android, iphone, html, css

After googling for sometime, decided to go with 420px width images with following tag

```
<image href="xxx.jpg" width="100%" />
```

Though image is scaling to mobile screen width, its quality is compromised in case of horizontal orientation (800px).

What would be best way to handle this situation?

Comment: Are you creating Mobile website by using HTML5 or else?

Comment: why dont you just remove the `width` property?

Comment: @PareshMayani Yes, Im developing a html5/css3 mobile WEB SITE

Comment: @rajakvk ok now i have edited tags, it would be easy to get answer if you tag properly.

Comment: @Sherif thanks. But on horizontal orientation Im seeing lot quality loss in images. :-(

Comment: @PareshMayani that is great... thanks for editing tags.

Comment: @rajakvk its weird: I mean it would be better to avoid scaling the image. 1 more thing this <image> tag ?! i only heard of <img>!

Comment: @Sherif: I think `<image>` might actually be supported in practice: Chrome 15 seems fine with it, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/nqeTC/

Comment: @Paul D. Waite: What on earth.

Comment: @BoltClock: the endless mysteries of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

> Though image is scaling to mobile screen width, its quality is compromised in case of horizontal orientation (800px).

Of course. If your image is only 420 pixels wide, it won’t look particularly good when scaled up to 800 pixels wide.

Different mobile devices have different screen widths. The iPhone 4 when held horizontally has 960 pixels available to it. I’m not sure if there are mobile devices with more pixels than that.

If you’re trying to maximise how good the images look, then you can either:

1. Keep the image as an HTML tag, and use a 960-pixel (or whatever the widest screen you want to support is) wide image. Mobile devices with smaller screens will scale the image down.
2. Insert the image as a CSS background image, and use [the `device-width` media query](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#device-width) to serve different images to different devices.

I’m not sure how well the second approach would work when the device switches between landscape and portrait though, I’ve never tried it.